# Need Help with a University Project to make a DApp

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

I want to make a DApp which stores information of people who have taken the COVID vaccine.
Information to be stored will be:

- Name of the Person
- Date of Birth
- Some Form of PIN Provided by the Government
- Photograph of the Person
- Receipt which is Received after taking the vaccine
  (Please suggest any other info which can be stored)

Since there is a growing number of Fake Covid Vaccine Cards/Certificates I thought of making this project.

After the Data is stored, the person can then present this as a proof for travelling, booking flights, etc.

I am new to developing DApps and I don't know how to go about starting this project. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You don’t save those data directly on the blockchain… those are private information and should not be saved on public chains. Take look at identities, DID, SSI and verifiable credentials

Comment: @MajdTL Thank You for the Comment. I did look for DID and SSI but they look a bit complicated for a beginner like me. If you have a good resource to learn and implement, it would helpful. I also looked at IPFS but I dont think thats safe to store private info either.

Comment: Yes it is indeed very complicated even for advance developers but it is the only correct way to implement digital vaccine and proofs . No don’t save private data on ipfs that is also bad.

Comment: What u can do for a simple project is to save the private data in database and be creative with merkle trees to generate proofs and validate the saved data and try somehow to link the persons data in ur database to a blockchain ids  / ethereum address . It is not simple for beginners but easier than the best approach